# Difference between char *a[10]; and char (*a)[10];

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following statements?

```
char *a[10];

char (*a)[10];
```

Answer (score 6):

The former is an array of 10 `char` pointers. The latter is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`'s.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *a[10];
```

This declares array of `10` pointers to `char` .

Whereas , this -

```
char (*a)[10];
```

declares pointer to array of `10` `char`'s